# struct proc_dir_entry Definition in Kernel

Tags: kernel, definition

Where is `struct proc_dir_entry` defined in linux kernel?
in `/linux/proc_fs.h` it is just declared as: (kernel 3.10)

```
struct proc_dir_entry;
```

and I think because of this I get this error:

```
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

at this line of code though including `/linux/proc_fs.h`:

```
while(strcmp (my_dir_entry->name,"tcp"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is defined in `fs/proc/internal.h`.

Comment: I've seen a patch here [link](https://github.com/yshui/spl/commit/f2da471c29bbf73702398147baed39f9b08f719b). can I apply this patch to be able to use this structure in userspace program?

Comment: This is an internal structure, I don't suggest you to use it userspace. If you really want to use it userspace, make a syscall that returns this.

Comment: Had they removed its definition because it cause some vulnerabilities ?

Comment: They didn't remove it. They just moved it where it should have been initially.

Comment: How to include this header file in kernel module source file?

Comment: #include "fs/proc/internal.h" maybe?