# proc shortcut available in 3.11 or new version of kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, proc

Does proc_root_fs(or proc_root), proc_net, etc still exist in the kernel 3.11 or newer?
How could I get proc_dir_entry reference to root of /proc(i.e /proc) directly?

I run into ' dereferencing pointer to incomplete type' error for proc_dir_entry struct is defined in fs/proc/internal.h, refer to this [struct proc_dir_entry Definition in Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334023/struct-proc-dir-entry-definition-in-kernel).

- proc_root_fs:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-proc/
- proc_root: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/root.c?v=3.11#L239
- proc_root: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/root.c?id=refs/tags/v3.13#n243

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I don't think you need to dereference a proc_dir_entry pointer in order to work with proc.

Comment: I want to enumerate dir/file entry in the /proc by using proc_dir_entry's subdir field.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question "What are you trying to accomplish?", I think.

Comment: Sorry, this is [what I have done](https://github.com/schemacs/schemacs/blob/master/kernel/setproctitle.c#L90)，but I don't want to create the proc entry, I want to enumerate the files under /proc.

Comment: If /proc is mounted you could use VFS functions to access it, but I don't think it's common to do that.